# Number of years calculation between two date in java( date collect from edit text)

Tags: android

I want to calculate number of year between two date in one of my form develop by android studio. i have two editText( startdate and enddate). and another editText for age.

my date format in edit text like 17/08/2015 and i am using this code in a button but wher i click the button it's shown unexpected age in age_in_year editText.what is the problem in my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            String dateStart = startdate.getText().toString();
            String dateStop = enddate.getText().toString();

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            Date d1 = null;
            Date d2 = null;

            int age = 0;
            try {
                d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
                d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

                //in milliseconds
                double diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

                double diffYears = diff / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                age = (int) Math.round(diffYears);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            age_in_year.setText(String.valueOf(age));
        }
```

Comment: Please put an example of the dates input format.

Comment: use joda time library